# Unable to add ppa repository (14.04)

Tags: ppa, add-apt-repository

There are no proxies involved and I have already tried (repeatedly) to reinstall my ca-certificates but I still am unable to add ppa repositories.

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:libccd-debs
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:libccd-debs'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

I tried it on another computer and had no difficulties so I'm confident the problem is local to my machine. Any help would be greatly appreciated
using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What if you manually add the the key and an entry to `sources.list.d`? Does the PPA work then?

Comment: When I tried to do sudo apt-get update I get the following error for each repository I added  
  
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 99D4A9FBA0D65078  
  
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BBADE7CA9D188262

Comment: You have to add the key too: http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=vindex&search=0x99D4A9FBA0D65078&fingerprint=on

Answer (score 0):

As you are receiving this error message after adding the PPA by editing your `list` files

```
W: GPG error: ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 99D4A9FBA0D65078 W: GPG error: ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BBADE7CA9D188262
```

you have to add the key manually as well.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys BBADE7CA9D188262
```